# Eliminating Javascript daylight saving time gap, a cross-browser solution

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser, timezone, dst

After lots of hassle I finally found the actual problem. It's the gap induced by daylight saving and the fact that different browsers act differently if timezone is set on UTC+3:30 (I'm not sure of other timezones).

Here's a snippet to generate the problem (the problem is reproducible if your system's TZ is set to UTC+3:30):

```js
function zeroPad(n) {
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= 2 ? n : new Array(2 - n.length + 1).join('0') + n;
}

document.write("<table border='1' cellpadding='3'><tr><td>Input date</td><td>Parsed timestamp</td><td>Output date</td></tr>");

var m = 22 * 60;
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
  var input = "3/21/2015 " + zeroPad(Math.floor(m / 60)) + ":" + zeroPad(m % 60) + ":00";
  var d = new Date(input);
  var output = d.getFullYear()
    +'-'+zeroPad(d.getMonth()+1)
    +'-'+zeroPad(d.getDate())
    +' '+zeroPad(d.getHours())
    +':'+zeroPad(d.getMinutes())
    +':'+zeroPad(d.getSeconds());
  
  
  document.write("<tr><td>" + input + "</td><td>" + d.getTime() + "</td><td>" + output + "</td></tr>");
  m = m + 15;
}
m = 0;
for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
  var input = "3/22/2015 " + zeroPad(Math.floor(m / 60)) + ":" + zeroPad(m % 60) + ":00";
  var d = new Date(input);
  var output = d.getFullYear()
    +'-'+zeroPad(d.getMonth()+1)
    +'-'+zeroPad(d.getDate())
    +' '+zeroPad(d.getHours())
    +':'+zeroPad(d.getMinutes())
    +':'+zeroPad(d.getSeconds());
  
  
  document.write("<tr><td>" + input + "</td><td>" + d.getTime() + "</td><td>" + output + "</td></tr>");
  m = m + 15;
}

document.write("</table>");
```

I've run it on Firefox and Chromium and here are what they say:

[image]

The parts within the red boxes are the range of times in which the gap happens. My problem is that components like calendars usually depend on date objects with time part set to "00:00:00" and they've got a loop generating new dates by adding a day worth of timestamp to the previous date. So once an object falls into `3/22/2015 00:00:00` it will be considered `3/22/2015 01:00:00` or `21/3/2015 23:00:00` (depending on the browser) and hence the generated dates will be invalid from that point of time forth!

The question is how to detect such date objects and how to treat them?

Comment: Don’t pass a “formated” date value to your script, but the timestamp value instead – and then use the Date object’s `UTC` methods. (Or pass the actual values you need from the server in the first place, eliminating the issue completely.)

Comment: @CBroe Using timestamp does not solve anything. `"3/22/2015"` and `1426969800000` are the same to Javascript and they produce the exact same object.

Comment: Do you have the ability to control the output from the server or are these dates coming from an external system?

Comment: I do but that's not what the question asks. Even though I'll be grateful if you could comment on that.

Comment: I wrote a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bj98fpxj/1/ wich could help you to understand what's happen

Comment: There is normaly a **gap** when changing from winter time to summer time and a **overlap** when changing back to winter time.

Comment: I found this: [Ext.Date.parse - problem when parsing dates near daylight time change.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253924-Ext.Date.parse-problem-when-parsing-dates-near-daylight-time-change.)

Comment: Iran time switch on 22th, but European switch on *a Sunday between 25th and 31th*, and US switch on April *a Saturday between 1st and 7th* (or maybe more)... So your snippet don't show any problem. Please change your sample to expand time test for going on something like from  march 15th to april 15th.... I'ts the 1st reason because my test rule prompt only failed conversions.

Comment: U could test by running: `env TZ=US/Central firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658` and run my last snippet

Comment: @Mehran No, it's not linked to `UTC+03:30`, but to *`Iran time`*! Try to run your browser as last comment purpose.

Comment: What's about [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) !?

Comment: *After lots of hassle **you** finally found the actual problem*? That's not well! Good practice is to include `*thanks to ... for pointed out the real problem*`! So I've helped you and didn't recieve *accepted* part of bounty or a simple `thanks`! That's not well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) will save you lots of headache, and is the easiest way to achieve cross-browser compatibility for this sort of thing.

```
var m = moment.utc("3/22/2015","M/D/YYYY")
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Using UTC for this is important since you don't want to be affected by the user's time zone.  Otherwise, if your date fell into a DST transition, it could be adjusted to some other value.  (You're not *really* intersted in UTC, you're just using it for stability.)

---

In response to this part of your updated question:

> To simplify the question, I'm looking for a function like this:
>
> ```
> function date_decomposition(d) {
>     ...
> }
>
> console.log(date_decomposition(new Date("3/22/2015 00:00:00")));
> => [2015, 3, 22, 0, 0, 0]
> ```

While it's now clear what you are asking for, you must understand it is *not possible* to achieve your exact requirements, at least not in a cross-browser, cross-region, cross-timezone manner.

- Each browser has it's own way of implementing the string-to-date parsing.  When you use either the constructor `new Date(string)` or the `Date.parse(string)` method, you're invoking functionality that is *implementation specific*.

  [There's a chart showing many of the formatting differences here.](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)
- Even if the implementation were consistent across all environments, you'd have regional formatting and time zone differences to contend with.

  - In the case of regional formatting issues, consider `01/02/2015`.  Some regions use `mm/dd/yyyy` ordering and will treat this as January 2nd, while other regions use `dd/mm/yyyy` ordering and will treat this as February 1st.  (Also, some parts of the world use `yyyy/mm/dd` formatting.)

    [Wikipedia has a list and map of where in the world different date formats are used.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)
  - In the case of time zones, consider that [October 19th, 2014 at Midnight (00:00) in Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/rio-de-janeiro?year=2014) *did not exist*, and [November 2nd, 2014 at Midnight (00:00) in Cuba](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/cuba/havana?year=2014) existed *twice*.

    The same thing happens on other dates and times in different time zones.  From the information you provided, I can deduce that you are in Iran time zone, which uses UTC+03:30 during standard time, and UTC+04:30 during daylight time.  Indeed, [March 22, 2105 at Midnight (00:00) *did not exist* in Iran.](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran?year=2015)

    When you try to parse these invalid or ambiguous values, each browser has its own behavior, and there indeed differences between the browsers.

    - For invalid times, some browsers will jump forward an hour, while others will jump backwards an hour.
    - For ambiguous times, some browsers will assume you meant the first (daylight-time) instance, while others will assume you meant the second (standard-time) instance.

Now with all of that said, you can certainly take a `Date` *object* and deconstruct its parts, quite simply:

```
function date_decomposition(d) {
    return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate(),
            d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()];
}
```

But this will *always* be based on the local time zone where the code is running.  You see, inside the `Date` object, there is just one value - a number representing the elapsed milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` (without leap seconds being considered).  That number is UTC-based.

So, in recap, all of the issues you are having are related to the way the string was parsed into the `Date` object to begin with.  No amount of focusing on the output functions will help you to resolve that in a completely safe manner.  Whether you use a library or write your own code, you'll need to obtain that original string of data to get the result you are looking for.  By the time it's in a `Date` object, you've lost the information you need to make this work.

By the way, you might consider watching my Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals), which covers much of this in even greater detail. Module 7 is entirely about JavaScript and these sorts of gotchas.

Comment: Even though this library sounds promising but my problem is that I'm using ExtJs and I've got no control over the code that instantiate the Date object. I was hoping to  find a way to work with Date objects previously instantiated like `new Date("3/22/2015")`.

Comment: Why didn't you say so?!  Ext.js has [a whole API of its own for date formatting](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Date)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it's no use! I'm developing a locale file for ExtJs and I'm writing a bunch of `Ext.Date.format` functions myself. And I'm stocked with the date objects handed to me. No matter what, they are off the clock and I can not extract the date components out of them properly. As the question states I'm trying to extract a date object's component out of it regardless of the client's timezone. I need the components as they were generated by the server.

Comment: The thing is - the `Date` object doesn't preserve the values that were used to created it.  It only preserves what it thinks is the equivalent UTC timestamp.  So any solution you might come up with will pass through time zone conversion in some way or another.

Comment: Your tests show exactly what I described in my answer, though I had the browsers reversed.  It actually looks like which side they error on may have changed in recent versions, so I edited my answer to be less specific about which browsers go which way.

Comment: With regard to how to detect and compensate for this - **YOU CAN'T**.  It's not possible.  The data you need is lost.  Sorry, I know you don't want to hear that, but it's the truth.

Comment: BTW - your example is exactly the reason why the new HTML5 date input types return a string and not a `Date` object.  Any third-party datepicker control that returns only a `Date` object has not thought about this problem.

Comment: Even `momentjs` is not working properly! Executing `moment("3/22/2015").add(1, "d").format()` outputs `"2015-03-23T01:00:00+04:30"` on my computer!

Comment: Yes, it is working properly. As I already explained at the top of this answer, you would need to use UTC for the stability you're looking for.  Think of it this way, both `moment` and `Date` represent a date *at at specific time*. (Date should have been called DateTime).   If you don't supply a time, it chooses midnight.  If midnight doesn't exist, it picks a time that does.

Comment: Another way you could go about it without using UTC is like this:  `moment("3/22/2015","M/D/YYYY").add(1,"d").startOf("day").format()`.  It's really important to specify the format string in the moment constructor.  Without it, it falls back to the Date object's behavior.

Comment: But the `.startOf("day")` is not accepted! And `moment("3/22/2015","M/D/YYYY").add(1,"d").format()` returns `"2015-03-23T01:00:00+04:30"`! I still think that it needs amendment.

Comment: What do you mean it's not accepted? [here are the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

Comment: I mean adding a day to `3/22/2015 00:00:00` should not result in `3/23/2015 01:00:00`! The momentjs library should be aware of the fact that this particular day is 23 hours instead of 24.

Comment: As soon as you do `moment("3/22/2015","M/D/YYYY")`, the time is at 1:00 because midnight doesn't exist.  It uses the start of day for the date you provided.    Next you add a day with `.add(1,"d")`, but you are now not at the start of *that* day, because one day past 1:00 is going to leave you at 1:00 on the next day.  Moment doesn't remember the intent of the original expression, it just knows that you're advancing by a day.  So you'd have to use `startOf("day")` if that's what you're after.

Comment: I completely understand your reasoning and why momentjs acts as it does, I just think it's not something some developer expects. Personally I want a date library to know which days are 24 hours and which are 23, just like knowing which years are 365 and which are 366. When you ask some date library to add a year to `22/3/2015` you don't expect to see `21/3/2016` in result (if 2015 is a leap year).

Comment: Yes, I agree with that statement.  What JavaScript needs is a library that separates a `Date` from a `DateTime`, and other distinct types.  Shoving everything into one type is what creates these uncertainties..  [I've discussed this on moment.js issues before](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/961#issuecomment-23616809).  I've *started* on such a library, but haven't had time to complete.  Essentially, it would be a port of [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) to JavaScript.

Comment: I hope you don't find me arguing but I disagree with your statement when you say it's all the result of not distinguishing between `Date` and `Datetime`! Even if there're different classes for date and datetime, I expect both of them to know of the DTS effects. I mean adding `+1d` to `3/21/2015 13:00:00` should give `3/22/2015 13:00:00` and not `3/22/2105 14:00:00`. The only case I would expect to see the later result is when `+24h` is added.

Comment: @Mehran What if you add a year to `2/29/2012` (which is a leap year)? If `2/29/2013` is known as an invalid date, I don't think it's so far fetched to receive `2/28/2013` or `3/1/2013` as an output. Raising an exception in this case may be even more surprising, as a user would expect the library to handle it "automatically". From Matt Johnson's comment, it seems like `3/22/2015 00:00:00` does not exist for your stated timezone, so `moment.js` making an assumption of `3/22/2015 01:00:00` when just `3/22/2015` was given sounds very reasonable, and is less surprising than raising an exception.

Comment: @user193130 The problem I'm asking about is not "how to store invalid dates?", it's related to date manipulation rather than storing it. Right now, adding `1d` to `3/21/2015 08:00:00` will result in `3/22/2015 09:00:00` which I think is incorrect. The proper way of implementing this kind of stuff usually is to store the UTC timestamp (which is not affected be DST or anything else like TZ) and use it for manipulation. Then put it through some conversion (like DST and TZ) before giving it out. This is the common way for implementing nonlinear systems.

Comment: @Mehran - That's *exactly* what moment is doing, and what the js Date object is doing - it internally stores a UTC timestamp, and converts it on the way out.  The part you seem to be missing is that it also has to convert it *on the way in*.  The example you just gave above, starting at `8:00`, will *not* result in `9:00` because `8:00` is *valid*.  You seem to be expecting the same behavior for all possible local date/time values, and that just can't happen because local clocks are non-linear (due to the DST adjustments).

Comment: One should read this answer before proceeding further with JavaScript date and time manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

#### Date Parse (1st answer before modified question)

This would parse input and isolate each value.

```js
function dateDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate(),
             d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds() ];
};
function dateUTCDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getUTCFullYear(),d.getUTCMonth()+1,d.getUTCDate(),
             d.getUTCHours(),d.getUTCMinutes(),d.getUTCSeconds() ];
};

function pdte() {
  var ndte=new Date(Date.parse(document.getElementById('datein').value));
  var ar=dateDecomposition(ndte);
  document.getElementById('yyyy').innerHTML=ar[0];
  document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML=ar[1];
  document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML=ar[2];
  document.getElementById('HH').innerHTML=ar[3];
  document.getElementById('MN').innerHTML=ar[4];
  document.getElementById('SS').innerHTML=ar[5];
  ar=dateUTCDecomposition(ndte);
  document.getElementById('Uyyyy').innerHTML=ar[0];
  document.getElementById('Umm').innerHTML=ar[1];
  document.getElementById('Udd').innerHTML=ar[2];
  document.getElementById('UHH').innerHTML=ar[3];
  document.getElementById('UMN').innerHTML=ar[4];
  document.getElementById('USS').innerHTML=ar[5];

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='';
  for (var i=1426896000000;i<1427068800000;i+=1800000) {
      ar=dateUTCDecomposition(new Date(i));
      var cmp=Date.parse(ar[0]+"/"+ar[1]+"/"+ar[2]+" "+ar[3]+":"+ar[4]+":"+ar[5]);
      var re=dateDecomposition(new Date(cmp));
      var fail=0;
      for (var l=0;l<6;l++) { if (ar[l]!==re[l]) fail=1 };
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+=fail+" -- "+ar.join(":")+'<br />';
  };
};

document.getElementById('datein').addEventListener('change',pdte,true);
window.onload=pdte
```

```html
<input id="datein" value="2015/03/14 12:34:56" />
<table border=1>
  <tr><td>Locale</td>
    <td id="yyyy"></td>
    <td id="mm"></td>
    <td id="dd"></td>
    <td id="HH"></td>
    <td id="MN"></td>
    <td id="SS"></td>
  </tr><tr><td>UTC</td>
    <td id="Uyyyy"></td>
    <td id="Umm"></td>
    <td id="Udd"></td>
    <td id="UHH"></td>
    <td id="UMN"></td>
    <td id="USS"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="test"></div>
```

#### Testing rule #1

Searching for *gaps* from year 2000 to year 2015, by 1/2hour steps

```js
function dateDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate(),
             d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds() ];
};
function dateUTCDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getUTCFullYear(),d.getUTCMonth()+1,
             d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(),
             d.getUTCMinutes(),d.getUTCSeconds() ];
};

for (var i=946684800000;i<1420070400000;i+=1800000) {
      ar=dateUTCDecomposition(new Date(i));
      var cmp=Date.parse(
          ar[0]+"/"+ar[1]+"/"+ar[2]+" "+
          ar[3]+":"+ar[4]+":"+ar[5]);
      var re=dateDecomposition(new Date(cmp));
      var fail=0;
      for (var l=0;l<6;l++) { if (ar[l]!==re[l]) fail=1 };
    if (fail!==0) {
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+=fail+
          " -- "+new Date(i)+" -- "+ar.join(":")+'<br />';
    }
}
```

```css
div#test {
  font-family: mono, monospace, terminal;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
   <div id="test"> </div>
```

At all, this seem not to be a javascript bug, but I found this about *ExtJs*:
[Ext.Date.parse - problem when parsing dates near daylight time change.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253924-Ext.Date.parse-problem-when-parsing-dates-near-daylight-time-change.)

#### Second testing rule

As this question was modified several times, there is a test rule working on last 10 years, by 15 minutes steps, for showing **gaps** AND **overlaps**:

```js
function dateDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate(),
             d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds() ];
};
function dateUTCDecomposition(d) {
    return [ d.getUTCFullYear(),d.getUTCMonth()+1,
             d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(),
             d.getUTCMinutes(),d.getUTCSeconds() ];
};

var end=(Date.now()/900000).toFixed(0)*900000;
var start=end-365250*86400*10;
for (var i=start;i<end;i+=900000) {
  ar=dateUTCDecomposition(new Date(i));
  var cmp=Date.parse(
      ar[0]+"/"+ar[1]+"/"+ar[2]+" "+
      ar[3]+":"+ar[4]+":"+ar[5]);
  var re=dateDecomposition(new Date(cmp));
  var fail=0;
  for (var l=0;l<6;l++) { if (ar[l]!==re[l]) fail++ };
  if (fail!==0) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+=
      fail+" -- "+new Date(i)+" -- "+ar.join(":")+'<br />';
  } else {
    ar=dateDecomposition(new Date(i));
    var cmp=Date.parse(
          ar[0]+"/"+ar[1]+"/"+ar[2]+" "+
          ar[3]+":"+ar[4]+":"+ar[5]);
    if (cmp != i) {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+=
      fail+" -- "+new Date(i)+" -- "+ar.join(":")+'<br />';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div#test {
  font-family: mono, monospace, terminal;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
   <div id="test"> </div>
```

You could test this by running your prefered browser under some differents timezones:

```
env TZ=Iran firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Iran opera http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Iran chrome http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Iran chromium http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Europe/Berlin firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Europe/Berlin opera http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Europe/Berlin chrome http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=US/Central firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=US/Central opera http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=US/Central chrome http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Asia/Gaza firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Asia/Gaza opera http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
env TZ=Asia/Gaza chromium http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048205/1765658
```

I hope that you will be able to create your own testing rules for your *ExtJS extensions*, taking ideas from this last snippet.

#### Screenshoots

TZ=Iran Chromium

[image: TZ=Iran chromium]

TZ=Iran Iceweasel (firefox)

[image: TZ=Iran iceweasel]

TZ=US/Central Chromium

[image: TZ=US/Central chromium]

TZ=US/Central Iceweasel

[image: TZ=US/Central iceweasel]

TZ=Asia/Gaza Chromium

[image: TZ=Asia/Gaza chromium]

TZ=Asia/Gaza Iceweasel

[image: TZ=Asia/Gaza iceweasel]

Comment: Set it to `2015/03/22 00:00:00` and you'll see

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your *problem*, I've tested this under Firefox and Chrome, under Linux, and by using android browser, for same results: *locale line match entry*.  What's your timezone?

Comment: `Iran Standard Time (UTC+03:30)`, when I enter `2015/03/22 00:00:00` in the text box it outputs; Chromuim: `Locale | 2015 | 3 | 22 | 1 | 0 | 0`, FireFox: `Locale | 2015 | 3 | 21 | 23 | 0 | 0`. UTC in Chromium is `2015-3-21 20:30:0` and `2015-3-21 19:30:0` in FF. It all seems to be related to my TZ!

Comment: Can you formulate the problem? Where and when it happens? How to detect it and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript dates are parsed in the local time of the browser, unless you use the ISO date format `"2015-03-22"`, which will be parsed as UTC. In your case, since you control the server, and you know the dates are actually UTC, you could leave the format the way it is and parse the date, then subtract the timezone offset value from the date to convert it to UTC. The following function should return exactly the results you requested in your last use case. You could obviously modify this to format the string in any way you see fit.:

```
function date_decomposition(dateString) {
    var local = new Date(dateString);
    var d = new Date(local.valueOf() - (local.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));

    return [ d.getUTCFullYear(), 
            (d.getUTCMonth() +1 ),
            d.getUTCDate(),
            d.getUTCHours(), 
            d.getUTCMinutes(),
            d.getUTCSeconds() ];
}
```

The only gotcha about this approach is that if you change your date format on the server to use the ISO 8601 date format, it will still subtract the timezone offset and you'll end up with the wrong output.

To be 100% safe, you *should* format the date string using the ISO 8601 date format, like `"2015-03-22"` or `"2015-03-22T00:00:00Z"`. Then you could delete the line that subtracts the timezone offset from the parsed date and it'll work correctly with any ISO date string:

```
function date_decomposition(dateString) {
    var d = new Date(dateString);

    return [ d.getUTCFullYear(), 
            (d.getUTCMonth() +1 ),
            d.getUTCDate(),
            d.getUTCHours(), 
            d.getUTCMinutes(),
            d.getUTCSeconds() ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the variable length argument constructor.

```js
function convert(dateStr) {
  var date = dateStr.split('/');
  return new Date(date[2], (date[0] | 0) - 1, date[1]);
}
                  
function formatDate(d) {
  function pad(i) {
    return i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
  }
  return d.getFullYear()
       + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1)
       + '-' + pad(d.getDate())
       + ' ' + pad(d.getHours()) 
       + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) 
       + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds())
}
  
var str = formatDate(convert('3/22/2015'));

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Here's what your snippets say in my browsers. *FF:* `2015-03-22 03:30:00` and `2015-03-21 19:30:00` respectively. *Ch*: `2015-03-22 05:30:00` and `2015-03-21 20:30:00` respectively. Do you see the problem? None of them are `2015-03-22 00:00:00`!

Comment: @Mehran, then just adjust for their timezone and use the `*UTC*` methods.

Comment: None of your four snippets output `2015-03-22 00:00:00`! I'm looking for a function which takes in `new Date("3/22/2015")` and outputs `"2015-03-22 00:00"` regardless of the client's timezone while the output is generated like `d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()`.

Comment: Your snippet still outputs: `2015-03-22 01:00:00` in my Chromium browser :)

Comment: And `2015-03-21 23:00:00 ` in my FireFox!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more on the approach. The browsers are behaving exactly as expected because they are both aware of the [Upcoming Daylight Saving Time Clock Changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html). So, your Chromium browser knows that at 12:00 Midnight local time in march 22, needs to move the clock forward to to 1:00 AM and your Firefox Browser knows that at Midnight Sat-Sun local time in march 22, needs to move the clock back to to Sat 11:00 PM.

There is a reason for the different time zones to be defined based on UTC. **UTC is a standard, not a timezone.** If you want to be cross browser you need to live by standards. Stick to UTC, store in UTC and do all date calculations in UTC. If you have a calendar component tell your component you are passing the dates in UTC. When you need to display the date to the user (thus browser dependent) you (if you are not using a component) or your calendar component are the ones responsible to check if daylight savings time is in effect, and adjust the date to be displayed accordingly.

¿How do you know if daylight savings time is in effect?

Check this [article about adding methods to the date object](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldst.htm) to do exactly that. The logic behind the code is that the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time are different if daylight saving time is in effect or not. If you just want to check the code here are the two functions:

```
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I got the solution of your problem**

It will surly help you

**First of all I would like to explain daylight time.**

**Daylight time:** During the summer days are longer; the sun rises earlier and sets later. Congress decided several decades ago that it would be better to have more daylight in the evening than in the morning, so they came up with daylight savings time. The clocks are shifted ahead one hour in the spring and back one hour in the fall. That way, you don't have sunrise at 4:00 a.m. and sunset at 8:00 p.m., but sunrise at 5:00 a.m. and sunset at 9:00 p.m., in the middle of summer. They figured people would use less electricity to light their houses in the evenings, and so forth.
So now, most of the country uses daylight savings time in the summer, and standard time in the winter. [yahoo link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100904143838AAlT1XK)

**Firstly I would like to Give you a solution of your problem:**

Set you computer's (Tested on win 7) time zone to GMT+3:30 and change your date to 23-march-2015.
and run your code on both browsers (chromium/mozila). 
you will find the same result (i.e. +1hr to your input time)

yepppii the problem is solved.

you will get +1hr added in your input time, because after March,22 2015 at 12:00 AM (for GMT +3:30) day light Saving time begins. ([you can check it here](http://24timezones.com/world_directory/current_tehran_time.php) also from here [here](http://prntscr.com/6j4gdn))

**Now the reason for this:**

please have a look on this screen-shot : http://prntscr.com/6j4gdn (on win 7)
here you can see "The day light Saving time begins on March,22 2015 at 12:00 AM.

Means time will be shifted 1 hr ahead after March,22 2015 at 12:00 AM.(only for those countries which uses daylight saving time system )

so if you changes the time to March,23 2015 the daylight saving period starts for (e.g. GMT+3:30) 
and you will find correct out put on both browsers.

I guess chrome always uses daylight saving time system (only for those countries which uses daylight saving time system) 
I have tested it by changing time of my system (but not 100% sure)

on the other hand mozila supports daylight saving time system. So after March,22 2015 at 12:00 AM for GMT+3:30 mozila will add 1hr to your input dateTime

I guess it would be helpful to all of you.